# Window dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection

I want to use Unity dependency injection in WPF application. My Window throw System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:

> "For type MainWindow found no default constructor".

This is my code:

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();
container.RegisterType<IService, MyService>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository, MyRepository>();
container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public MainWindow(IService service)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     service.Test();
}
```

Comment: "and I don't know how to use Google" - hahahaha

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Vandalizing questions is not cool.

Comment: @RBarryYoung That's true.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's not cool to change the title of a question to something utterly unrelated to what the question is actually about.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was just trying to return it to what it was before you vandalized it. If you want to be snarky, use the comments. Using your site privileges to mutilate someone else's question to mock them is way over the line.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: In particular this is not about a missing default constructor, it's rather why Unity is not using the dependency/contructor injection as expected.

Comment: @blurray: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to have a default constructor for your view in order for your WPF application  to work properly.

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

and then define the parameterized constructor like this :

```
public MainWindow(IService service) : this()
{
     service.Test();
}
```

Comment: You need the parameterized constructor to call the default constructor with a `:this()` at the end of the method signature. otherwise `InitializeComponent();` won't get called

Comment: Default ctor needed only if views instantiated via XAML, right? If we instantiate views from code, view is not nave to have default ctor.

Comment: Imho, this does not address the OPs problem of Unity not calling the parameterized constructor with constructor injection.

Comment: I agree with @tym32167. But this is a **MainWindow**. How does it work without a default constructor, even if we write everything in code behind?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain : Sorry I missed it. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @IDisposable It will work ok, if you are using some DI container to create an instance of MainWindow (as example https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/c53fc1e97794d900e508ae425298e05b90c765c2/src/Arma3BE.Client/Bootstrapper.cs#L26 )